# VBA: Error 13 for an If statement with two conditions

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am receiving a 'run-time error13 type mismatch for a line that uses two Variants in an if statement.

Another post said that the problem could be fixed by reading my values into Variants instead of Ranges because they may be 'Error'. This had no effect and I am still receiving the same error.

What is causing the error? Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub FillPartNumRev()

Dim i As Long, ii As Long
Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
Dim q1 As Variant, q2 As Range
Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, r3 As Long
Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long, c3 As Long

Workbooks("IPIC-DATA3.xlsx").Activate

Do While i < 5000 & ii < 5000

    r1 = 8: c1 = 1
    r3 = 8: c3 = 3
    i = 8
    ii = 8

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set v1 = .Range(.Cells(r1, c1), .Cells(r2, c2))
        Set v2 = .Range(.Cells(r3, c3), .Cells(r3, c3))
        Set q1 = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2))
        Set q2 = .Range(.Cells(ii, 3), .Cells(ii, 3))
    End With

    If q1.Value <> v1.Value & q2.Value <> "" Then
'>>>error on this line
        v1.Copy q1
    ElseIf q1.Value <> "" & q2.Value = "" Then
        r1 = r1 + 7
        r2 = r2 + 7
    End If

    r4 = r4 + 1
    c4 = c4 + 1
    r5 = r5 + 1
    c5 = c5 + 1
    r3 = r3 + 1
    c3 = c3 + 1

    i = i + 1
    ii = ii + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Here is the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
Sub mcvExample()

Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range
Dim q1 As Range
Dim q2 As Range



Workbooks("YOUR-WORKBOOK-NAME-HERE.xlsx").Activate
'Please create a workbook in the same format & have it open



With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set q1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1))
Set q2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(2, 3))
End With

If x < 10 & y < 10 Then
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
End If







End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim v1 As Range`. But in general, try to build up some [mcve], with 3-4 lines.

Comment: Does `v1.Copy q.cells(1)1` resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't on the `If q1.Value <> v1.Value & q2.Value <> "" Then` line? You cannot compare multiple cells against mutiple cell like that.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't Jeeped

Comment: BTW, `&` is a string concatenation operator in VBA, use `And` for two bolleans.

Comment: I 'Dim V1 As Range' but it had no effect @Vityata

Comment: @KwonBlack - replace the `&` with `And` as mentioned by @Jeeped.

Comment: Good point Jeeped, didn't know that

Comment: Still gave me the same error after replacing the & with And @Vityata

Comment: Does that mean the error is from the two bolleans?

Comment: @KwonBlack - idk. On which line is the error? Can you build up a small, up to 10 lines code, which would be easily copied & paste, receiving the same error? The so called [mcve]?

Comment: You cannot ask `If A1:B1 = C5:D5 And C3:C9<>""` which is what the If is trying to do.

Comment: The error is on the line: 'If q1.Value <> v1.Value And q2.Value <> "" Then'

Comment: Why can't it be asked? @Jeeped

Comment: I'll try to do the MCV example @Vityata

Comment: @KwonBlack - it cannot be asked, because you get `error 13`. Try to write this in the Immediate Window and see: `?Range("A1:A5")<>Range("B1:B5")` Ranges are compared differently, e.g. by comparing them cell by cell for example.

Comment: If `q1.Value` or `q2.Value` is a `Variant/Error`, then you're implicitly converting an `Error` to a `String` or some other data type, and that can't be done. `If SomeError <> ""` is requiring a conversion from `Error` to `String`. You need to check both variants with `IsError` to know if the comparison is legal.

Comment: reinitializing i and ii to value 8 inside the do while loop will cause an infinite loop

Comment: Your MCVE turns `q1` into a single-cell range, which is a different scenario and behavior than your original code (single-cell's value will be a `Variant`, not a 2D array). See bottom part of below answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Another post said that the problem could be fixed by reading my values into Variants instead of Ranges because they may be 'Error'.

A `Range` won't be reading any value; a `Range` *is* the cell, not just its value:

```
Dim foo As Range
Set foo = sheet.Range("A1")
```

Reading a cell's value into a `String` is making an assumption:

```
Dim foo As String
foo = sheet.Range("A1").Value
```

Here if `Value` can't be converted to a `String`, you get a *type mismatch* error.

Same if you're comparing a cell's value to some string literal:

```
If sheet.Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
```

If `Value` can't be converted to a `String` for this comparison, you get a *type mismatch* error.

"Reading the value into a Variant" is indeed the solution:

```
Dim foo As Variant
foo = sheet.Range("A1").Value
```

Now this `foo` will be a `Variant/String` given a string `Value`, or a `Variant/Double` given a numeric `Value`, or a `Variant/Date` given a date `Value`... or a `Variant/Error` given an error `Value`.

This means you still can't assume this will work:

```
If foo <> "" Then
```

Because a `Variant/Error` read from a `Variant` local variable is not any different than reading a `Variant/Error` straight from `Range.Value`.

You need to eliminate the possibility of the variant subtype being `Error` in order to proceed to do anything with the value:

```
If Not IsError(foo) Then
    'type conversion is safe
    If foo <> "" Then ' or If CStr(foo) <> "" Then, for an explicit conversion
        '...
    End If
Else
    'foo contains an error value
End If
```

---

But that's not what you're having here.

```
Set q1 = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2))
```

`q1` is a `Range` object reference that spans 2 cells: its `Value` will therefore be a 2D variant array.

```
Set v1 = .Range(.Cells(r1, c1), .Cells(r2, c2))
'...

If q1.Value <> v1.Value [1] & q2.Value <> "" [2] Then
```

With `v1` also spanning multiple cells, its `Value` will also be a 2D variant array. So you're trying to apply the inequality operator `<>` between two 2D variant arrays [1]... and you can't do that. Then you try to apply the same operator `<>` between a 2D variant array and a string [2], and you can't do that either.

If you mean to compare each individual values in the arrays, you need nested loops to check each individual value.

Comment: I don't need to compare each individual value in the arrays, but rather the value of the entire 2D variant arrays.

Comment: @KwonBlack there is no such thing as "the value of the entire 2D variant array". An array doesn't have "a" value, it has "many" values.

Comment: If 'If foo <> "" Then' won't work, will I be able to do 'If foo < 1000000000000? In this case foo won't be more than 10-13 digits long.

Comment: The entire top part is addressing the `Variant/Error` concern. If `foo` is a `Variant/Error`, you can't compare it to anything without getting a type mismatch error. Not `""`, not `1000000000`, nothing. That's why you use `IsError` to rule out the `Variant/Error` possibility.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I'll try that